# passing values using get from a dropdown populated from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i have problem passing data from one page to another using GET, for example

i have these:

```
<form method=post action=edit.php>
<td><input type=text name=firstname></td>
<td>
<?
    $query="SELECT * FROM gender;
    $result = mysql_query ($query);
    echo "<select name=gender_id>";
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<option value=$nt[gender_id]>$nt[gender_name]</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
</td>
<td><input type=submit name=edit></td>
</form>
```

now to pass these to edit.php using GET

```
if($mode=="edit")
{
$fistname=$_GET["fistname"];
$gender=$_GET["gender_id"];
<td><input type=text name=firstname value="<? echo $fistname; ?>"></td>
```

Above is a working code for an input type text. I know how to pass values with input type text but my problem is that HOW WOULD I DO THESE WITH A SELECT tag WHICH HAS VALUES FROM A MYSQL DATABASE?.

Comment: i do not understand the problem what $gender contain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
    $query="SELECT * FROM gender;
    $result = mysql_query ($query);
    echo "<select name=gender_id>";
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    if ($nt[gender_id]==$_POST["gender_id"])
       $selected="selected";
    else
        $selected="";
    echo "<option ".$selected."value=$nt[gender_id]>$nt[gender_name]</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="GET" action="edit.php">
```

Or use `$_POST` in the script instead.

**EDIT, since you didn't bother putting your question in the question:**

As you iterate through the options, test the value of `$nt[gender_id]` and add the `selected` attribute to the one that matches.

Comment: you didnt get the point. ok let us say i should use post. then how should pass the value of the dropdown? for example a user chose female as her gender, then she tries to edit it to male, how can i echo the value gender which is female in the dropdown? same as i can echo her name after choosing the edit button. thank you.

Comment: ... You don't know how to write an `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

you were using `<form method=**post** action=edit.php>`, in that way you should use `$fistname=$_POST["fistname"]; $gender=$_POST["gender_id"];`

if you want to use `$fistname=$_GET["fistname"]; $gender=$_GET["gender_id"];`
you should use `<form method=**get** action=edit.php` but in that way, the thoses values will be visible in the url.

Comment: you didnt get the point. ok let us say i should use post. then how should pass the value of the dropdown? for example a user chose female as her gender, then she tries to edit it to male, how can i echo the value gender which is female in the dropdown? same as i can echo her name after choosing the edit button. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typographical error on your `edit.php` change `$_GET['fistname']` to `$_GET['firstname']`. Then edit:

```
<form method=post action=edit.php>
```

and put `method="get"`

```
<form method=post action=edit.php method="get">
```

And to prevent errors on `edit.php`. Add these:

```
if ((isset($_GET['firstname']) && (isset($_GET['gender_id'])) {
    //your code
} else {
    //some error message
}
```

Comment: my bad. typo error.. you didnt get the point. ok let us say i should use post. then how should pass the value of the dropdown? for example a user chose female as her gender, then she tries to edit it to male, how can i echo the value gender which is female in the dropdown? same as i can echo her name after choosing the edit button. thank you.